# QObject is an inaccessible base

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет. Не так давно начал программировать на Си++, помогите разобраться с такой проблемой. У меня есть класс `Joint_S1i`, который наследуется от класса `DataTransmissionChannel`, который в свою очередь наследуется от `QObject`. Когда я делаю сборку проекта мне компилятор выдает ошибку `‘QObject’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Joint_S1i’`. Я так понимаю это связано с использованием `connect` в моем классе `Joint_S1i`. Возможно я как то неправильно сделал наследование. Код ниже.

### joint_s1i.h

```
#include "datatransmissionchannel.h"

class Joint_S1i : DataTransmissionChannel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Joint_S1i(const quint16 &portIn = 42599,
                       const quint16 &portOut = 42600,
                       const QHostAddress &host = QHostAddress::LocalHost,
                       QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void run();
    void onManageSignal(const char &word);
    void runBufferController();
};
```

### joint_s1i.cpp

```
#include "joint_s1i.h"
#include "QtConcurrent"


Joint_S1i::Joint_S1i(const quint16 &portIn,
                     const quint16 &portOut,
                     const QHostAddress &host,
                     QObject *parent) :
    DataTransmissionChannel(portIn, portOut, host, parent)
{
    run();
}

void Joint_S1i::run()
{
    m_opened = true;
    m_buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    m_thread = new QThread();
    moveToThread(m_thread);
    connect(m_thread, &QThread::started, this, &Joint_S1i::runBufferController);
    m_thread->start();
}
```

### datatransmissionchannel.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QThread>
#include <QBuffer>

class DataTransmissionChannel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DataTransmissionChannel(const quint16 &portIn,
                                     const quint16 &portOut,
                                     const QHostAddress &host = QHostAddress::LocalHost,
                                     QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void stop();
    void runBufferController();

public slots:
    void onNewConnectionServerIn();
    void onNewConnectionServerOut();
    void slotServerInRead();
    void slotServerOutRead();

protected:
    QTcpServer *m_tcpServerIn = nullptr;
    QTcpServer *m_tcpServerOut = nullptr;
    QTcpSocket *m_tcpClientIn;
    QTcpSocket *m_tcpClientOut;
    quint16 m_portIn;
    quint16 m_portOut;
    QHostAddress m_host;
    QThread *m_thread = nullptr;
    bool m_opened;
    QBuffer m_buffer;
    qint64 m_maxBufferSize = 10000000;
};
```

### datatransmissionchannel.cpp

```
#include "datatransmissionchannel.h"
#include <QTextStream>

DataTransmissionChannel::DataTransmissionChannel(
        const quint16 &portIn,
        const quint16 &portOut,
        const QHostAddress &host,
        QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_host = host;
    m_portIn = portIn;
    m_portOut = portOut;
    m_tcpServerIn = new QTcpServer(this);
    m_tcpServerOut = new QTcpServer(this);
    QTextStream cout(stdout);
    if (!m_tcpServerIn->listen(m_host, m_portIn)) {
        cout << "Unable to start the incoming server on port " << m_portIn << ". Reason: " << m_tcpServerIn->errorString() << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (!m_tcpServerOut->listen(m_host, portOut)) {
        cout << "Unable to start the outgoing server on port " << m_portOut << ". Reason: " << m_tcpServerIn->errorString() << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "DataTransmissionChannel start server on " << m_host.toString() << ":" << m_portIn << endl;
    cout << "DataTransmissionChannel start server on " << m_host.toString() << ":" << m_portOut << endl;
    connect(m_tcpServerIn, &QTcpServer::newConnection, this, &DataTransmissionChannel::onNewConnectionServerIn);
    connect(m_tcpServerOut, &QTcpServer::newConnection, this, &DataTransmissionChannel::onNewConnectionServerOut);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда Вы пишите вот так

```
class Joint_S1i : DataTransmissionChannel
```

то это равносильно

```
class Joint_S1i : private DataTransmissionChannel
```

и DataTransmissionChannel скрыт от пользователей Joint_S1i

сделайте вот так

```
class Joint_S1i : public DataTransmissionChannel
```

и скорее всего все заработает

Comment: Да, это решило проблему, спасибо

Comment: (обычно спасибо здесь - это нажать треугольник вверх и галочку напротив ответа)

Comment: о, и тут минусатор нашелся. Минусатор, покажи личико!

Comment: KoVadim, к сожалению вверх треугольник не могу сделать, не хватает рейтинга.
Если не сложно в продолжение вопроса посмотрите этот пост https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1295546