# C++ QT запуск функции класса в отдельном потоке

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет. Не так давно начал программировать на Си++. У меня есть класс `Joint_S1i` и мне нужно запустить в отдельном потоке его функцию `void Joint_S1i::runBufferController()`. В документации QT к потокам в примере создается отдельный класс, который перемещается в отдельный поток через `moveToThread`, но я хочу просто запустить функцию уже созданного класса в потоке.
Что я пробовал:

### 1 moveToThread

```
m_thread = new QThread();
moveToThread(m_thread);
connect(m_thread, &QThread::started, this, &Joint_S1i::runBufferController);
m_thread->start();
```

### 2 QtConcurrent

```
QtConcurrent::run(this, &Joint_S1i::runBufferController);
```

Когда запускаю программу при обоих вариантах приложение падает. Падает именно на запуске потоков.
В дебаггере вижу вот такие сообщения

```
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
```

### .pro

```
QT -= gui
QT += core network concurrent

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
    datatransmissionchannel.cpp \
    joint_s1i.cpp

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    datatransmissionchannel.h \
    joint_s1i.h
```

### datatransmissionchannel.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QThread>
#include <QBuffer>

class DataTransmissionChannel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DataTransmissionChannel(const quint16 &portIn,
                                     const quint16 &portOut,
                                     const QHostAddress &host = QHostAddress::LocalHost,
                                     QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void runBufferController();

protected:
    QTcpServer *m_tcpServerIn = nullptr;
    QTcpServer *m_tcpServerOut = nullptr;
    QTcpSocket *m_tcpClientIn = nullptr;
    QTcpSocket *m_tcpClientOut = nullptr;
    quint16 m_portIn;
    quint16 m_portOut;
    QHostAddress m_host;
    bool m_opened;
    QBuffer m_buffer;
    qint64 m_maxBufferSize = 10000000;
};
```

datatransmissionchannel.cpp

```
#include "datatransmissionchannel.h"

DataTransmissionChannel::DataTransmissionChannel(
        const quint16 &portIn,
        const quint16 &portOut,
        const QHostAddress &host,
        QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_host = host;
    m_portIn = portIn;
    m_portOut = portOut;
    m_tcpServerIn = new QTcpServer(this);
    m_tcpServerOut = new QTcpServer(this);
    m_tcpServerIn->listen(m_host, m_portIn);
    m_tcpServerOut->listen(m_host, portOut);
}

void DataTransmissionChannel::runBufferController()
{
    while(m_opened) {
        bool emptyBuffer = false;
        if (m_buffer.size() < m_maxBufferSize * 0.2)
            emptyBuffer = true;
        if (m_buffer.size() > m_maxBufferSize * 0.8)
            emptyBuffer = false;
        if (emptyBuffer && m_tcpClientIn)
            m_tcpClientIn->write("Need data");
        if (m_buffer.size() == 0)
            this->thread()->sleep(1);
    }
}
```

### joint_s1i.h

```
#include "datatransmissionchannel.h"

class Joint_S1I : public DataTransmissionChannel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Joint_S1I(const quint16 &portIn = 42599,
                       const quint16 &portOut = 42600,
                       const QHostAddress &host = QHostAddress::LocalHost,
                       QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void run();
};
```

### joint_s1i.cpp

```
#include "joint_s1i.h"
#include "QtConcurrent"


Joint_S1I::Joint_S1I(const quint16 &portIn,
                     const quint16 &portOut,
                     const QHostAddress &host,
                     QObject *parent) :
    DataTransmissionChannel(portIn, portOut, host, parent)
{
    run();
}

void Joint_S1I::run()
{
    m_opened = true;
    m_buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    QtConcurrent::run(this, static_cast<void(Joint_S1I::*)()>(&Joint_S1I::runBufferController));
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "joint_s1i.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Joint_S1I joint_S1I;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Чтобы правильно решить, как исполнять что-то в отдельном потоке, нужно четче сформулировать задачу. Потому что возможно, это работа для std::async и Qt тут ни при чем

Comment: `QtConcurrent::run(this, &Joint_S1i::runBufferController);` что то я в документации не вижу такого синтаксиса.

Comment: `QtConcurrent::run` — то что ты ищешь... синтаксис с виду правильный и должен работать... сможешь [mcve] сделать?

Comment: @KoVadim, синтаксис который описан в документации `QtConcurrent::run(aFunction);` почему то не работает, qt creator его сразу красит красным. То что я написал нашел на просторах стек оверфлоу

Comment: То, что редактор "красит красным", ещё ничего не значит. Важно то, компилируется ли оно для начала.

Comment: @KoVadim, не компилируется. Пробую так `QtConcurrent::run(runBufferController);`, ошибка такая `invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Joint_S1i::runBufferController()`

Comment: QtConcurrent::run хочет функцию (или статическую функцию-член). А Вы ей подсовываете функцию член класса.

Comment: @KoVadim, если я сделаю функцию статической или просто вынесу за пределы класса, я боюсь я не смогу использовать объект класса буффер. Я могу как то передать ссылку на этот объект и использовать его в другом потоке без создания копии этого объекта?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, добавил минимальный пример. Вылетает когда доходит до `QtConcurrent::run`

Comment: Отправьте весь объект в другой поток. Иначе, придется заниматься синхронизацией обращений к буферу.

Comment: я только что попробовал запустить через `QtConcurrent::run(this, &MainWindow::foo);` - работает нормально. да, давно я не занимался Qt. Может покажете, что происходит в функции?

Comment: @KoVadim, в `runBufferController` ? Сейчас добавил пример, там все есть. Только что попробовал перенести напрямую без наследования в класс `DataTransmissionChannel` только доходит до `QtConcurrent::run` вылетает так как получен сигнал `SIGSTOP`. Если дебажить то что происходит внутри `QtConcurrent::run`, то в дебаггере валятся `RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'`

Comment: я не думаю, что это большая проблема, что оно не видит RTTI. Но в целом ошибка весьма странная

Answer (score 1):

Как выяснилось тут проблема не в запуске функции в отдельном потоке. Поток запускается. Проблема в моем буффере. Я использую класс `QBuffer`, который не потокобезопасный. Сначала я его открывал буффер для чтения/записи, а потом пытался запустить поток, который должен был получать доступ к тому же объекту `QBuffer`. Проблема была именно в этом. Попробовал запустить поток без открытия буффера и все заработало. Вот рабочий вариант:

```
QtConcurrent::run(this, static_cast<void(Joint_S1I::*)()>(&Joint_S1I::runBufferController));
```

Comment: добавлю, что более человеческим синтаксисом будет `QtConcurrent::run(static_cast<DataTransmissionChannel*>(this),
                      &DataTransmissionChannel::runBufferController);` и что вместо `this->thread()->sleep(1);` лучше использовать `QThread::sleep(1);`...